# How to make responsive content

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm confused how to make this code responsive. Please review the below example and let me know.

```css
#appalign{font-family:"montserrat-regular",sans-serif;margin-left:32%;margin-right:10%;text-align:justify;text-justify:inter-word}#appalign1{font-family:"montserrat-regular",sans-serif;margin-right:55%;text-align:justify;text-justify:inter-word}

#appalign2{font-family:"montserrat-regular",sans-serif;margin-left:55%;margin-right:%;margin-top:-10%;text-align:justify;text-justify:inter-word}
```

```html
<div id="appalign1">
  <p style="color: black">We believe in the power of a relationship – not just a relationship between you and us but with your customers as well. We work with you to deliver your message so that it captivates your audience and Target Group.<span style="font-weight:bold;color:black;"><font size="4"> We help you develop the right look, feel and personality</font></span> – a different<span style="font-weight:bold;color:black;"><font size="4"> brand image</font></span> that allows you to stand apart in the crowded market and above all get noticed. We make things simple and focus more on giving personal and effective customer service to you.</p>
</div>
<div id="appalign2">
  <p style="color: black">We provide<span style="font-weight:bold;color:black;"><font size="4"> advertising solutions</font></span> that integrates with your marketing to bring you effective results. We harness the power of new media to build a strong brand and till we are convinced about one, we won’t recommend it to you. We use a mix of<span style="font-weight:bold;color:black;"><font size="4"> online, print, email, and social media</font></span> channels to tell your brand's story in a way that resonates with customers and forms lasting bonds.</p>
</div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/RamBM/pen/pppbOB)

Comment: you can use [Media Queries](https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/CSS/Media_Queries)

Comment: @Evo I know, we have to write Media Queries in order to get website responsive. I'm stuck here to write responsive code for above code

Comment: Define "responsive". How do you want it to respond? To what?

Answer (score 2):

There you go. You were not usng the floats and etc. I've done it for you.

```
<div id="appalign1">
  <p style="color: black">We believe in the power of a relationship – not just a relationship between you and us but with your customers as well. We work with you to deliver your message so that it captivates your audience and Target Group.<span style="font-weight:bold;color:black;"><font size="4"> We help you develop the right look, feel and personality</font></span> – a different<span style="font-weight:bold;color:black;"><font size="4"> brand image</font></span> that allows you to stand apart in the crowded market and above all get noticed. We make things simple and focus more on giving personal and effective customer service to you.</p>
</div>
<div id="appalign2">
  <p style="color: black">We provide<span style="font-weight:bold;color:black;"><font size="4"> advertising solutions</font></span> that integrates with your marketing to bring you effective results. We harness the power of new media to build a strong brand and till we are convinced about one, we won’t recommend it to you. We use a mix of<span style="font-weight:bold;color:black;"><font size="4"> online, print, email, and social media</font></span> channels to tell your brand's story in a way that resonates with customers and forms lasting bonds.</p>
</div>

#appalign1 , #appalign2{float:left;width:50%;padding:0 20px;box-sizing: border-box;}

@media( max-width: 640px ) {
  #appalign1 , #appalign2 { width: 100%; }
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aEEmOp

Comment: It works great. But could you please `#appalign1 , #appalign2{float:left;width:calc(50% - 40px);padding:0 20px;}` explain this code

Comment: This code divides your sections into two equal columns. If you are new to CSS you can use bootstrap for structure building. Also you can use http://shoelace.io/. It will help you.

Comment: width:calc(50% - 40px) is not a good idea, it's better to use `box-sizing:border-box` or you will have to adpat the value each time you do a change

Comment: @TemaniAfif You are right.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to add a container and apply `display:flex` on it and avoid a lot on unnecessary CSS.

You can then switch direction of flex for small screen using media query if needed.

*You have to move all your inline style inside CSS file and remove the use of obsolete tag like `font`*

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.appalign {
  font-family: "montserrat-regular", sans-serif;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word
}

@media all and ( max-width: 660px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="appalign">
    <p style="color: black">We believe in the power of a relationship – not just a relationship between you and us but with your customers as well. We work with you to deliver your message so that it captivates your audience and Target Group.<strong> We help you develop the right look, feel and personality</strong>      – a different<strong> brand image</strong> that allows you to stand apart in the crowded market and above all get noticed. We make things simple and focus more on giving personal and effective
      customer service to you.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="appalign">
    <p>We provide<strong> advertising solutions</strong> that integrates with your marketing to bring you effective results. We harness the power of new media to build a strong brand and till we are
      convinced about one, we won’t recommend it to you. We use a mix of<strong> online, print, email, and social media</strong> channels to tell your brand's story in a way that resonates with customers
      and forms lasting bonds.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that this is possible using VW units. They're the units associated with setting the viewport width. There are some drawbacks, such as lack of legacy browser support, but this is definitely something to seriously consider using. Plus you can still provide fallbacks for older browsers like so:

```
p 
{
font-size: 30px;
font-size: 3.5vw;
}
```

https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

Comment: yes we can do this. But I'm having two `div` with different properties. Here I'm getting problem to make it responsive

Comment: Okey i get it try this https://codepen.io/Tipue/pen/pjdgad

Answer (score -1):

Please use this css it work fine.

```
 * {
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    *:before,
    *:after {
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    #appalign1{font-family:"montserrat-regular",sans-serif;width:50%;float:left;text-align:justify;text-justify:inter-word;padding-right:1%;}
    #appalign2{font-family:"montserrat-regular",sans-serif;width:50%;float:left;text-align:justify;text-justify:inter-word;}
```